# How to receive a recurring "Dwell" event for Android Geofence API?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-location, android-geofence

I'm having a play with this example project: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/tree/master/Geofencing

So from this sample, ENTER fires when the user was last outside of a geofence but is now within, EXIT fires in the same way (was in, but now is outside), and DWELL is more or less an ENTER event with a delay (has been inside a geofence for at least a certain amount of time).

What I'd like to do is have a recurring DWELL event fire - so after the DWELL event is detected, it reschedules a new one and checks again in the specified time frame.

Does anyone know how to go about this?

Thank you.